# How can i optimize the use of my convection oven?

Tags: baking, oven, convection

Is there a resource i can use to learn how to bake in my convection oven?  I know that it can improve the results greatly and i am just not understanding it.  I know that you are supposed to bake at 25 degrees lower temp but it seems like all my baked goods seem to dry out or brown too quickly.  I thought it was supposed to just bake things more evenly.

Comment: Could you describe for us a specific problem you have had?

Comment: You should also be reducing the cooking time, in most cases, not just temperature.

Answer (score 1):

A convection oven has a fan that blows hot air around the items being baked. The air flow will draw moisture from the food. To stop the drying out, you could tent the baking items with aluminum foil but that has two drawbacks: you waste aluminum foil and lots of times you do want your baking items to lose moisture during baking. Another issue as you noticed, it messes up the browning (Maillard reaction) of the baking process. Where you place your item to be baked with a regular oven has a big effect as well as the container.
The top of oven is hotter while the bottom of the oven is better for slow cooking. Place the dough in dark container for better browning.
Convection ovens change all of those variables. I recommend that you use recipes tailored for that type of oven. If you are concerned about being energy efficient. Bake more than one thing at a time. That's what I do. I use multiple timers and the location in the oven to place the various items for a fantastic meal or bake.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems that you are simply setting it too hot. No need for a resource, just experiment until you have found the correct temperature which works for you.

It seems that you expected to just set it 25 degrees lower than the old one. There are three reasons why it might now work. First, this advice usually assumes 25 Celsius, I don't know which units you are using, 25 F wouldn't have been enough. Second, it is rough advice, the difference needed is not perfectly linear. Third, ovens seldom have good thermostats. If your old oven was running a bit low, and the new one is running a bit high, then your new one will consistently overbake your old recipes if you use the same baking vessels and leave them inside for the same time. You will just have to get a feel for it until you know which temperature setting is good for which dish.

Answer (score 0):

They really shouldn't call these convection ovens. They should be called blower ovens. Normal ovens without the blower are convection ovens with the heat rising up the middle and cooler air falling around the outer lamination (shells) of air. That's convection.

When you place a cookie sheet, the hot air mushrooms in from the sides down on top of the cookie or biscuits or whatever, as well as directly heating the bottom surface. You don't have this with a blower oven.

A blower moves the hot air around and it's like the opposite of "wind chill" on a cold day. Because the air is blowing, it draws more heat from the heating elements as well as deposits more heat to all the surfaces. So for instance 400 degrees with 5 MPH of wind might feel like (and heat heat YOU up like 425 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Well all you need to do is bake on a lower stand which is given with microwave as it will cook it from the bottom as well as wont burn the top..